# How can I put a button into collapse?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to put a button into a collapse, I am using the collapse of `antd`,  that new button doesn't should open or close the collapse, I want to give her other functionality?

```
const {  Collapse, Button  } = antd;
const { Panel } = Collapse;

function callback(key) {
  console.log(key);
}

const text = ` hi `;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Collapse 

  defaultActiveKey={['1']} onChange={callback}>
    <Panel header={<Button type="primary">Primary Button</Button>} key="1" >
    <Button type="link">My button</Button>  > 
      <p>{text}</p>
    </Panel>
  </Collapse>,
  mountNode,
);
```

Why does the COLLAPSE open when I click the button? I don't want the COLLAPSE to open

Comment: There is 2 buttons, what button you want not to open the collapse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the button you want to not open the collapse is your `Primary Button` in header of `Panel`, To do that you have to control `activeKey` manually, and check that when user click on the Panel header are they click on the `Primary Button` or outside of it.

Try this:

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import * as antd from "antd";

const { Collapse, Button } = antd;
const { Panel } = Collapse;

const text = ` hi `;
export const App = () => {
  const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState(0);
  const isButtonClicked = useRef(false);

  const callback = key => {
    console.log(key, isButtonClicked.current);
    // Check if use click on the button don not update activekey
    if (
      isButtonClicked &&
      isButtonClicked.current &&
      isButtonClicked.current === true
    ) {
      isButtonClicked.current = false;
      return;
    }

    if (!activeKey) {
      setActiveKey(key);
    } else {
      setActiveKey(0);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Collapse activeKey={activeKey} onChange={callback}>
      <Panel
        header={
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              // set the isButtonClicked ref to tru when user click on Button
              isButtonClicked.current = true;
              // Do other functionality you want for this button here
            }}
            type="primary"
          >
            Primary Button
          </Button>
        }
        key="1"
      >
        <Button type="link">My button</Button> ><p>{text}</p>
      </Panel>
    </Collapse>
  );
};
```

I create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-bardeen-jio7u?file=/src/App.js:0-1053) to demonstrate it

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
const {  Collapse, Button  } = antd;
const { Panel } = Collapse;

function callback(key) {
  console.log(key);
}

const text = ` hi `;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Collapse  defaultActiveKey={['1']} onChange={callback}>
    <Panel header={<Button type="primary">Primary Button</Button>} key="1" > 
       <Button type="link">My button</Button> 
      <p>{text}</p>
    </Panel>
  </Collapse>,
  mountNode,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button inside a panel, the button code should be inside the panel, not inside its tag.. instead of:

```
<Panel header="This is panel header 1" key="1" 
<Button type="link">My button</Button>  > 

  <p>{text}</p>
</Panel>
```

this should be

```
<Panel header="This is panel header 1" key="1">
    <Button type="link">My button</Button>
    <p>{text}</p>
</Panel>
```